# Image upload to Google Cloud storage with Spring Boot works locally but when deploy it doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Got a bit of a weird one with GCS I have the following code for uploading images to GCS from my Spring boot application which is running on App Engine where it all works absolutely fine when I run it on my machine but as soon as I deploy it doesn't work. I don't get any errors except a 500 response from the server.
Am I missing something?

```
    Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();
    private Bucket bucket = storage.get(bucketName);
    if(bucket == null) {                
        bucket = storage.create(BucketInfo.of(bucketName));
    }
    
    System.out.println("storage: "+storage);
    BlobInfo blobInfo = storage.create(
        BlobInfo
            .newBuilder(bucketName, fileName)
            .setAcl(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Acl.of(com.google.cloud.storage.Acl.User.ofAllUsers(), com.google.cloud.storage.Acl.Role.READER))))
            .setContentType("image/jpeg")
            .build(),
            fileStream.getBytes());

//Don't get this print line :/ 

            System.out.println("File: "+fileStream.getBytes());
            String fileUrl = blobInfo.getMediaLink();
```

I have tried it with credentials and without and have also updated all of my gcloud libraries so they are all running the latest versions as I did initially think it could have been that.

Any pointers would be a great help!

EDIT: added Pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>AppId</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>My-App</name>
    <description>My app description</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--mpm -->
        
        <!-- JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...) -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- END mpm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
            <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>checkout-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.63</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>    
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!-- add appengine-maven-plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <projectId>GCLOUD_CONFIG</projectId>
                    <version>main</version>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many factors that causes a `500` response when an app is deployed on App Engine (out of memory, unhandled exceptions, very slow website, etc.). I tested your code and I was able to make it work locally and successfully deployed it on App Engine by simply applying your code using this [Java 11 Springboot Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/quickstart) guide.

There's little information and I'm not sure how your entire Springboot application works so I suggest that you study the documentations, test your code snippet locally using the sample, then try to redeploy again.

Comment: Thanks Donald, I am using Java 8 at the moment as I have not managed to migrate over just yet, do you think that might be causing any issues?

Did you have to set any permissions on the App engine server?
I have updated my question with the full function 

I will try your suggestion now with a completely blank spring boot app, thanks

Comment: I don't recall having to set any permissions (I'm working on a single test project). It's very unlikely that you're getting this issue just because you're using an older runtime. If this could help, here's a [Java 8 Springboot sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java8/springboot-helloworld) also maintained by GCP.